# Subreport variable always return null

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I need to put a variable in the master report which value came from a subreport. I followed instructions from the web, but I've always got null. For testing, I put "18" in the expression of subreport variable, but returns null.

Can someone help me? I will put the JRXML below.

I created a variable var1 in master report:

1. Name: var1
2. Calculation: System
3. Reset type: Report
4. Increment type: None

In the subreport, I created the variable returnValue

1. Calculation: No Calculation Function
2. Expression: 18
3. Increment type: None
4. Reset type: Report

In the master, I configured the return value:

1. From Variable: returnValue
2. To Variable: var1
3. Calculation Type: Nothing

Following the two xml files

---

### MASTER

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 4.0.2  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="master" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <variable name="var1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="System"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="153" y="26" width="100" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[MASTER]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="246" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="80" y="10" width="360" height="50"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="returnValue" toVariable="var1"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["sub1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="149" y="147" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{var1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

---

### SUBREPORT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 4.0.2  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sub1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <variable name="returnValue" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[18]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="212" y="24" width="100" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[SUB 1]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. One problem is that the sub report is never getting executed since its main `dataset` does not return any row. So change the `When No Data Type` of sub report from `<NULL>` to `All Sections No Detail` -

[image]

2. Secondly the variable `returnValue` in Sub report have `Reset type` as `None` -

[image]

3. Finally the variable `var1` rendered using `TextField` should have `Evaluation Time` as `Report` -

[image]

Below are updated JRXMLs -

### MASTER

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.15.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.15.0-dd49bfb94918336b8321d5507193f0169ead4e95  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="master" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d1a326d7-0db4-41f6-9791-6c0abc454731">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <variable name="var1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="System"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="153" y="26" width="100" height="30" uuid="ccc1c45e-e056-4a8e-8adc-cebefd388bc9"/>
                <text><![CDATA[MASTER]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="246" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="80" y="10" width="360" height="50" uuid="e251bfe7-5e81-4b79-9bc6-5f0e6c1d9555"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="returnValue" toVariable="var1"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["sub.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="149" y="147" width="100" height="30" uuid="24c3289e-f7a5-4137-9254-1fa2605f6741"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{var1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

### SUBREPORT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.15.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.15.0-dd49bfb94918336b8321d5507193f0169ead4e95  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sub1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="97bfa906-b658-45f6-aff8-3bfa505251b3">
    <variable name="returnValue" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[18]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="212" y="24" width="100" height="30" uuid="9332a235-2823-4b53-b6f8-0a7c56d58aee"/>
                <text><![CDATA[SUB 1]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Finally ran into this and got my report working. Tx!. I wonder how one is supposed to know all this.